# How to pass data between ASP.net, sql server and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I'm trying to develop a web site that receives data from SQL server, then show info on listbox and textbox, and when user select an option then insert data to a table in the database.

My ASP.NET controls are:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Start" OnClick="btnInsert_Click" />
```

I need the data loaded to a listbox, but not sure how to do directly. To retrieve the info and see if its working I did this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView2.DataSource= reader;
GridView2.DataBind();
con.Close();

var nProject = GridView2.Rows.Count;

for (int b = 0; b < nProject ; b++)
{
 ListBox1.Items.Add(GridView2.Rows[b].Cells[0].Text);
}

}
```

Then I tried to set the selected info to a textbox, but nothing happens (because I managed to insert data from textbox to a SQL Server INSERT) :

```
protected void ListBox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
        Response.Write("ListBox selectedIndexChanged");

    }
```

The info is send back to the database with a button click:

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var IP = "111.111.11";
        txtStatus.Text = "Start";
        txtProject.Text = "PR-02";


        var indice = 0;
        // This always returns "0"
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            indice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;

        }

        txtProject.Text = indice.ToString();
         
        // Sql INSERT works fine, but only with info manually created. I can't get the real info to             work
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[table3]
       ([project]
       ,[user_task]
       ,[status]
       ,[ip]
       ,[location])
 VALUES
       ('" + txtProject.Text + "', '" + txtUser.Text + "', '" + txtStatus.Text + "', '" + txtIP.Text + "', '" + txtLocation.Text + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Regarding your insert statement, [always use parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Comment: Why are you choosing to develop a new website with ASP.NET Web Forms? It's 2021 - don't start off using a dead framework! There's lots of great, more modern options: ASP.NET Core MVC, Blazor, ASP.NET Core Web API + SPA framework etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Page_Load is one of the first events to run every time there is a call to the server, this means that it runs before the btnInsert_Click event.

This means that you are repopulating the ListBox1 before checking the SelectedItem, this is why *it always returns "0"*

You have to consider this and use something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Page.IsPostBack || Page.IsCallback) return;
   (...)
}
```

It is hard to understand what you want to do, but I think the ListBox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged is useless if you correct the Page_Load event.

Side notes:

- You should really start by putting using statements where you can (on SqlConnection and SqlCommand)
- Watch out for Sql Injections, may be a simple test program, but you should **NEVER, EVER** do this: @"INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ('" + txtProject.Text + "'"
  use parameters instead:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("****"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[table3] ([project]) values (@project)", con))
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project", txtProject.Text);
}
```

- It seems you are using .Net Framework with aspx pages, you should really consider using newer technologies (.net core).